# Keep consistent name-mangling for c++ libraries in both mingw and g++ (64bit)?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, mingw, name-mangling

I am building an interop layer that will import some c++ mangled names (C# .NET Core, using CppSharp, if you are interested).

I'd like to generate a single interop code base. If I build a c++ library in mingw and g++ (64bit), can I be garunteed the mangled names will be the same?

Side note: I am aware Visual C++ does things completely differently. That is why I am wondering if mingw will generate the same mangled names as g++.

Comment: There is no guarantee that mangled names will work with different versions of the same compiler.  `extern "C"` however will always work.

Comment: Really? The same compiler, but different version? I'd figure that would be a huge no-no to change. I guess *different* compilers are our the window then.

Comment: If you need to control the exact spelling of an exported symbol, you are going to have to manually assign it. MSC uses [.DEF files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28d6s79h.aspx), and I'm sure GCC has provisioning for this as well.

Comment: I just compiled dcmtk for both mingw and gcc. https://gist.github.com/pauldotknopf/d94c3900a3cf16e0c21c6ebbdb01bcd8 The results look similar. The code exported functions seem to be there (ignoring compiler generated exports). I will look into .DEF files. Thanks.

Comment: @RichardCritten Please don't spread FUD like that, some compilers (including gcc and clang) do provide some guarantees. Even MSVC has some (more with recent releases).

Comment: @MarcGlisse please include links to backup your claims

Comment: https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html documents the ABI used by gcc and clang (except one version of clang meant to be compatible with msvc). https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compatibility.html. If you also want compatibility using library objects, https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html. Etc.